# Prevent Javascript from continuing on when a function hasn't returned?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've got something like...

```
//start function
var info = getinfofromserver();
//Continue with function
```

where `getinfofromserver()` does an AJAX call. I've noticed that my code will continue running even if `var info` has not been assigned a value from `getinfofromserver()`. I'm wondering if there is anyway I can get my code to 'hold' on till this function has returned? I am aware there are ways of doing call backs etc. from within the `getinfofromserver()` but I'd prefer to do it at this point so I can keep my code DRY.

Comment: Can you also post the code from inside getinfofromserver?

Comment: What does keeping your code DRY mean? Because WET code sounds scary.

Comment: Using asynchronous callbacks for this purpose is extremely idiomatic in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

By default in many frameworks, the AJAX request is, by definition, performed asynchronously.  This means that your function will continue after sending the request, and results will be handled by the callback function that you register.

Some frameworks, or if you code down to the browser level, provide you the option of performing the request synchronously instead, but it takes a little searching to find the right parameter for your framework or browser.

Answer (score 0):

1. The 'A' in AJAX stands for 'Asynchronous'. You should almost always use callbacks instead of a synchronous call.
2. Nothing about using a callback in this manner violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to perform synchronous AJAX callbacks (which is quite a nice oxymoron, but who cares).

For example, `jQuery.ajax` offers a `async` option ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)) and other JavaScript framework behave similarly. However, I'd strongly urge you to consider using *real* AJAX - that's how it's designed.

Using synchronous callbacks might be much more work for you than a plain AJAX request with a callback. You shouldn't need to repeat any code in either case, so I don't see why using AJAX violates `DRY` …

Answer (score 0):

Others have addressed the asynchronous nature of AJAX calls. But regarding your more general question:

> I'm wondering if there is anyway I can get my code to 'hold' on till this function has returned?

That's actually what's happening; it won't continue with the rest of your code until that function returns. It's just that the function is probably returning before the AJAX call gets a response. But this is a different matter; the AJAX call is not a function.